# Can you recommend a robust OpenAPI 2.0 provider?

Tags: authentication, web, single-sign-on, openid

Help me find a robust OpenID 2.0 provider!

We're looking at various SSO solutions for our organization, and I would like to suggest OpenID as a viable option, since (a) there is good consumer support in a number of web applications, and (b) it's simpler to implement than Shibboleth, which is the alternative technology.  However, this requires that we find a robust OpenID provider, ideally one meeting the 2.0 specification.

The only solutions I've come across so far are:

- [Atlassian Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/)

  This looks great, although the $4000 price tag may make it a tough sell.
- [Community-ID](http://source.keyboard-monkeys.org/projects/show/communityid)

  This looks like an interesting idea, but I'm not sure the project quality is at a suitable level (yet).  In particular, it's not clear if LDAP support actually works (which will be a requirement in our environment).

Have you implemented OpenID in your environment?  What are you using?  Have you selected an alternative SSO technology?

Comment: You may want to correct the headline of your question - "OpenAPI 2.0 provider" is confusing when you are looking for an OpenID provider.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another to look at: https://www.myopenid.com/

Comment: For various reasons (e.g., FERPA concerns), I'm not sure that a hosted solution would be appropriate.  Also, it's not clear that myOpenID can integrate with our own authentication infrastructure.